# Base64 Decode : Specific String Incorrect Padding (with correct padding)

Tags: python, base64, python-3.6

I am trying to Base64 decode a string (into bytes) using Python's base64.b64decode(str) method:

> 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy

and I am ensuring it has a multiple of 4 ='s for padding or out of frustration any of these:

> 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy=
>
> 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy==
>
> 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy===
>
> 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy==================================================

and yet I still get "Incorrect Padding" on Python v3.6.1. Other strings are fine.

I show a colleague, he tries on Python 2 and observes the same response.

I note removing the first "4" is enough to ensure the Base64 decode works.

I have skim read [Python's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) (noting casefold doesn't apply for Base64) and haven't yet ventured further into [RFC3548](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html) but wondered if someone else had encountered something similar before. Anyone have any clues :)? Surely this can't be a bug in Python's Base64 decoder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked it out.

Each character of Base64 text is 6 bits of the raw's 8 bits. If a character is mid-way through the raw's bytes then you are missing some remaining bits. The Wikipedia article (and many online answers) seems to use padding as interchangeable for a '0' byte which is not the case (in the Base64 dictionary it should be encoded as an A).

Padding is not interchangeable for missing data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# We use hexlify for debugging.
import binascii

# We use the Base64 library.
import base64

# Base64 works on multiples of 4 characters..
# ..Sometimes we get 3/2/1 characters and it might be midway through another.
def relaxed_decode_base64(data):

 # If there is already padding we strim it as we calculate padding ourselves.
 if '=' in data:
  data = data[:data.index('=')]

 # We need to add padding, how many bytes are missing.
 missing_padding = len(data) % 4

 # We would be mid-way through a byte.
 if missing_padding == 1:
  data += 'A=='
 # Jut add on the correct length of padding.
 elif missing_padding == 2:
  data += '=='
 elif missing_padding == 3:
  data += '='

 # Actually perform the Base64 decode.
 return base64.b64decode(data)

# Debugging
print(str(relaxed_decode_base64('46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy')) + '\n')

testString = ''

for count in range(0, 1024):
 testString += '/'
 print(str(len(testString)) + ' - ' + testString)
 print(binascii.hexlify(relaxed_decode_base64(testString)))
 input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem in your data, not related to Python:

```
$ echo 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy | base64 -d
ãª­jrÚÄg7 2base64: invalid input
$ echo 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy= | base64 -d
ãª­jrÚÄg7 2base64: invalid input
$ echo 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy== | base64 -d
ãª­jrÚÄg7 2base64: invalid input
$ echo 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy=== | base64 -d
ãª­jrÚÄg7 2base64: invalid input
$ echo 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ayy==== | base64 -d
ãª­jrÚÄg7 2base64: invalid input
```

I managed to decode it this way (removed the last 'y'):

```
$ echo 46oWrWpy2gTEGwNnN6Ay | base64 -d
ãª­jrÚÄg7 2
```